# How to filter on managed metadata column using REST API in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, term-store, rest

I am accessing couple of forms libraries and lists from SharePoint sites using the ReST API at _vti_bin/listdata.svc. I can use filters like $Select, $Expand etc and it works fine.

However few of these lists do contain columns from managed metadata term store. I can see the values in the view when I login to the site. But I do not get those columns in the data retrieved using the API.

Can someone help me to understand how I may get the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a few articles, not all types of columns are available/supported via REST in SharePoint 2010, including managed metadata columns.

Not Supported

- Managed Metadata
- Managed Metadata (Multi)
- Publishing HTML
- Publishing Hyperlink
- Publishing Image
- Media Field
- Summary Links
- Publishing Image

Source: http://platinumdogs.me/2013/03/14/sharepoint-adventures-with-the-rest-api-part-1/